# Using .net class with Phalanger in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, web, phalanger

How can I reference to an assembly and use it's classes (ex: `XamlWriter` to generate xmal) in Phalanger web applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the reference into web.config, into

```
<phpNet>
    <classLibrary>
        <add assembly="PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Phalanger will import all the objects from the assembly, and you can use them from PHP using classic PHP syntax (since Phalanger 3.0), e.g:

```
use System\Windows\Markup;
$saved = Markup\XamlWriter::Save($obj);
```

Comment: I remember you told me you would improve this feature. Nice work. I should rewrite Sc2ParserApe sometime.

Comment: It works, but why do I have to include the prefix here (ex: Markup\XamlWriter, Windows\ResourceDictionary,...)? Is there any way to get rid of these prefixes?

Comment: It is standard PHP syntax. You can only use PHP aliasing, to shorten namespaced names: "use System\Windows\Markup\XamlWriter as X; X::Save($obj);"